# Show that a polynomial of degree 4 is birational equivalent to a polynomial of degree 3

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose that $f_{4}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 4 with no multiple roots, $C$ is the curve defined by $y^{2}=f_{4}(x)$, I want to show that there is a polynomial $f_{3}(x)$ of degree 3 with no multiple root such that $C$ is birational equivalent to the curve defined by $y^{2}=f_{3}(x)$, I completely don't know how to do it, can anyone help me

Comment: Isn't it a standard result about elliptic curves?

Answer (score 4):

This is a cross-site duplicate of [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239746/birationally-transforming-a-quartic-elliptic-curve). I present the highest-scoring answer from there as a community-wiki  answer here for the benefit of future MSE users.

[Myshkin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/43108/myshkin):

> The method explained in Husemöller's book on elliptic curves is as follows:
>
> Take a general quartic $v^2=f_4(u)=a_ou^4+a_1u^3+a_2u^2+a_3u+a_4$, and let
>
> $$u=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\qquad v=\frac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^2} y$$
>
> Substituting you get:
>
> $$v^2=\frac{(ad-bc)^2}{(cx+d)^4}y^2=f_4\bigg(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\bigg)$$
>
> which implies
>
> $$(ad-bc)^2y^2=f_4\bigg(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\bigg)(cx+d)^4=\sum_{i=0}^4a_i(ax+b)^{4-i}(cx+d)^i=$$
> $$=c^4f_4\bigg(\frac{a}{c}\bigg)x^4+f_3(x)$$
>
> where $f_3(x)$ is a cubic polynomial whose coefficient of $x^3$ is $c^3f'_4(a/c)$. For $a/c$ a simple root of $f_4$ and $ad-bc=1$, this leaves the cubic equation $y^2=f_3(x)$.
>
> From here you can use the tools you mention in the question to take care of the cubic.